# Having issue of creating two graph at same time for second instance of Camera filter out pin disable

Tags: c++, directshow, graphedit

Directshow GraphEdit filter trying to design Video / Image captured.
Requirement is very simple We have to run the preview of the camera and capture the image/video based on button click.

**Issue:**
Capture Graph and Video graph cant create at the same time. As Camera Pin is disabled during the second instance of the same camera. I am not able to identify the filter which we can use to create a single graph for capturing the video and image.

Comment: That is an expected behavior as a camera is an exclusive resource! Windows 10 introduced a frame-server for this, but it could be that the frame-server is only used for Media Foundation and not for DirectShow.

Comment: See links in "Related" section on the right >>>